# need help in ng-disabled with || ((OR) Opeatator

Tags: angularjs

Is it correct way to use ng-disabled with two conditions if not please tell me correct way . I am new to angular.

```
  <button type="submit" ng-disabled="!(posttext || active)"  name="Post-submit"  
value="Post-submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">Post</button>
```

Comment: looks fine to me.  the equation will be evaluated with posttext and active being treated as 'truthy/falsey' values.

Comment: depends on your expectations...but syntax is fine. Is there a problem?

Comment: yes its not working accordingly?

Comment: With this syntax if any of the variables is truthy it will not disable the button, what are your expectations?

Comment: don't judge other if you are not in that position